# MySQL Gap between two rows less then 15 minutes

Tags: mysql

I have a sensor mac detection table

[image]

My sensors are placed at two geographical locations, Whenever a sensor connects to a mac It creates a record. Now I need to query like how many time a mac 'q2w3e4r5t6y7u8i9' was detected from a sensor 1 to sensor 2 and the gap was 30 min.

In simple words, I need to check if mac was moved from one place to another place in 30 min.

Desired output for input

```
mac: 3w4e5rt67y8
point 1: 1 (sensorId)
point 2: 2
interval: 48 hours
```

[image]

You can see

```
1. 3w4e5rt67y8 was detected by sensor 1 on 24 Feb 2020 at 19:29
2. 3w4e5rt67y8 was detected by sensor 2 on 25 Feb 2020 at 19:29
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: That is not 30 minutes.. that's 24 hours

Comment: yes.. I have written just for reference. Gap is variable

Answer (score 0):

In your query, select from the table, then join to the table the same record table, with matching mac and different sensorid, where the createdAt field is less than `DATEADD(HOUR, HowManyHoursYouWant, Table1.createdAt)`, along with the appropriate `GROUP BY`.

There wasn't any db fiddle for me to quickly throw this in and check for syntax, so this is pure psuedocode, you will probably need to massage it into place...

```
SELECT Table1.mac, Table1.sensorid, Table1.createdAt 
FROM Table AS Table1
JOIN Table AS Table2 ON
    Table2.mac = Table1.mac AND
    Table2.sensorid != Table1.sensorid AND
    Table2.createdAt <= DATEADD(HOUR, 2, Table1.createdAt)
GROUP BY Table1.mac, Table1.createdAt;
```

As you can, `DATEADD( HOUR, 2, Table1.createdAt)`, the gap is set to `2 HOURS`.  You can set it to any amount, as you had stated, in making it a variable.

Please add a db fiddle if you'd like me to test this out further.  It would be super helpful.  Hope this helps.